# Distance measurements between lat and long co-ordinates from database table using Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, distance

I want to calculate the Distances  between lat and long co-ordinates from a database table with the first queried result in Table being reference for the other lat and long locations. The Db table will consist of "USR,REF,LONG,LAT" .

Ultimately my goal is to make a GUI where user looks for a REF record . The user will then make a selection from a table . And based on the record selected , which will be used as reference for the other lat long points , the distant between the referenced lat & long points and the other lat & long points differences will be displayed  .

I have tried the haversine formula . But i see most of the tutorials show only two lat and lot points for distant measurements

````
import sys
import math 


def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    # convert decimal degrees to radians    
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula    
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) *math.sin(dlon/2)**2

    c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a))

    km = 6367 * c

    return km

conn = pypyodbc.connect(# My MsAccessDB Location)


cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "SELECT*FROM Test_dist ORDER BY Licensee"

cursor.execute(query)

results = cursor.fetchall()


for x in results:

     print(x) ```



OUTPUT


(' ABC JIM', 469.55, 18.533333, -33.85)
(' CALLY', 383.5125, 23.460278, -33.234722)
(' ROSS', 469.55, 21.983333, -34.166667)
(' SALLY M', 383.5625, 23.2325, -33.072222)
('KRACE', 400.36, 23.5688, -33.045668)
('LEEMER', 202.36, 23.2566, -33.158859)



When i run the code it displays all my records . I am not sure how to implement this into the haversine function thou as I would need to do it from my database table .
````

Comment: Are you trying to put the values of row  1 's lat and long and each other row's lat and long into that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you would do if you want to compare each row to the long and lat of the first row.

```
for i in range(1,len(results)):
     print haversine(results[0][2],results[0][3],results[i][2]results[i][3])
```

Comment: Thank you . Looking at your'e answer it seems so easy now . I will definitely have to do some homework and more reading on my For loops . Thank you